# Create themable field group

Tags: entities, 8, theming

I have a custom entity with several fields. Now I would like to group the fields and give each group it's own twig template so that I would be able to compose a page (my custom entity) containing several sections (field groups).

How would you do that? Do I group the fields in the entity preprocess function and give each group it's own `'#theme'`, do I have to change my `hook_theme` or should the grouping already happen in the controller? Or maybe create a computed field to store the other fields?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field group module is designed to solve this exact problem The Drupal 8 version is reasonably up-to-date.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.
>
> https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group

Comment: Thank you, this would probably work, but I would really like to be able to code this myself and just need a hint how to do it the "right" way in Drupal 8. Still appreciate your help!